# React Native Maps liteMode not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

**Code**

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';

import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height;
const LATITUDE = 37.78825;
const LONGITUDE = -122.4324;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO;

const SAMPLE_REGION = {
  latitude: LATITUDE,
  longitude: LONGITUDE,
  latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
  longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
};

class Map extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const maps = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      maps.push(
        <MapView
          liteMode={true}
          key={`map_${i}`}
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={SAMPLE_REGION}
        />,
      );
    }
    return (
      <ScrollView style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}>
        {maps}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
    height: 200,
    marginVertical: 50,
  },
});

export { Map };
```

**Error**

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file its defined in.

Check the render method of MapView.

**Issue**

I only get this error when I add the liteMode prop to MapView.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
<MapView
          liteMode
          key={`map_${i}`}
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={SAMPLE_REGION}
        />
```

Check that example file
https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/examples/LiteMapView.js

Comment: This is the same thing as saying liteMode={true}